# Loop through a file and paste columns next to one another

Tags: bash

Given I have a python script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

for i in range(1,4):
    print i
```

I want to run it in a bash loop for 3 times but I want to add the output as columns rather than concatenating. Is there a way to achieve this?

Output:

```
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Comment: There is literally a command called column.

Comment: Well, but that cannot being used here.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
$ for i in {1..3} ; do echo $i $i $i ; done
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`pr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pr) command:

```
for i in 1 2 3 ; do
    python a.py
done | pr -t -3
```

Output:

```
1           1           1
2           2           2
3           3           3
```

---

Btw, to get the numbers from `1` to `3` you need to use:

```py
range(1,4) # <-- 4, not 3!
```

in Python